# What kind of punctuation is on-topic for <{([brackets])}>?

Tags: discussion, tags

The <{([[brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/brackets)])}> tag has

> Brackets are tall punctuation marks used in matched pairs within text,
>   to set apart or interject other text. They have a variety of meanings
>   in different programming languages. DO NOT USE THIS for the IDE, use
>   [adobe-brackets] instead.
>
> Brackets are tall punctuation marks used in matched pairs within text,
>   to set apart or interject other text. They have a variety of meanings
>   in different programming languages.

Assume we want to keep this tag, what kind of brackets are they supposed to be used for? {[curly-braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/curly-braces)}? ([parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parentheses))? The [[square-bracket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/square-bracket)]? The <[right-angle-bracket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/right-angle-bracket)>? Anything else?

Comment: Why do we even have any of these tags in the first place?

Comment: @4castle maybe because punctuation is hard to search for.

Comment: At first I thought this tag had confused itself for [Brackets](http://brackets.io/), but after realizing that [tag:adobe-brackets] was a thing, I'm not thinking that anymore.  I don't know if it'd be a good idea to get rid of those tags, but I can't really find any rationale to leave them in place, either.

Comment: I can see using the tag for "what does this syntax do" type questions, but it looks like these tags are being misused a lot. I think I'm going to do some minor cleanup.

Comment: My minor cleanup ended up being more major than I expected. I just finished re-tagging about 140 questions (90% of which were to use [adobe-brackets] instead).

Comment: I'm with @4castle, I think there's a very large number of completely useless tags. Are there seriously people who are particularly interested in questions relating to [while-loop]s? Is anyone aided by knowing that a question relates to which thing is the [closest]? Do we really need a tag that lets us know a question concerns how to [compare] two entities?

Comment: And don't get me started on all the tags relating to specific jQuery functions...

Comment: I picked Duke for my bracket. Er, wait...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Definition from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bracket):

> Bracket
>
> a :  one of a pair of marks `[ ]` used in writing and printing to enclose matter or in mathematics and logic as signs of aggregation —called also square bracket
> b :  one of the pair of marks `< >` used to enclose matter —called also angle bracket
> c :  parenthesis
> d :  brace

From looking at the questions, all of these `[] () {} <>` are on-topic for [brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/brackets). While people may disagree on what these symbols are called, all of these are called brackets by a significant amount of people, so it's still searchable.

Some common **GOOD** reasons to use the tag might be:

1. What does this syntax mean?
2. How do I parse strings with balanced delimiters?
3. Why does adding brackets to this code produce different results?

Some common **BAD** reasons to use the tag are for questions like:

1. How do I use the Adobe Brackets IDE? (use [adobe-brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adobe-brackets))
2. Any question about quotation marks `"` or `'`, because nobody calls them brackets, and that's not a helpful keyword. (perhaps use [quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quotes) instead)
3. Any question which happens to use a bracket somewhere in the code, but it's not the subject of the question.
4. How much more money can I make while staying in the same tax bracket?

---

### Do we need the [brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/brackets) tag?

I don't think we *need* the tag, but it doesn't seem to be hurting. For the most part, people use it responsibly, and not as a meta-tag. It's purpose is primarily to increase searchability for a defined class of questions. It's not really a tag people would favorite/follow, and it wouldn't work as the only tag on a question.

Comment: I think the last two points in your "Do we need the tag" section are useless for evaluating whether a tag should exist or not

Comment: @TinyGiant I agree, that's mostly just there to acknowledge that the tag isn't quite the same as other tags out there.

Comment: I agree with your agreeing with me.

Comment: @TinyGiant I agree with your agreeing with him agreeing with you.

Comment: It's delightful to see everyone in agreement.

Comment: @webnoob I disagree... someone has to.

Comment: @Braiam - I disagree with you - there is never a need for someone to disagree

Comment: @YowE3K - I'm in full agreement with your disagreement of Braiam's disagreement with my agreeing to all the agreements ...

Comment: I wouldn't pay any attention to M-W, ever since they defined "literally" as "figuratively"

Comment: @JanDvorak Why is that a problem with the dictionary? That's a correct definition according to modern usage (although it's more like slang)

Comment: If that's the case, they should also define it's as its and vice versa, synonymize their/they're, note that "alot" isn't just a furry animal but could also mean "a lot" and rarely even "allot"... At least that would be a bit useful in decoding some of the more egregious typos.

Comment: @JanDvorak I don't seem to understand your argument. "Literally" in place of "figuratively" isn't a typo, it's a rhetorical device called overstatement.

Comment: It's not an overstatement, it's an abuse of a word whose purpose is to denote "not figuratively"

Comment: @JanDvorak That's kind of the point of making an overstatement, but okay.