# Isn't every [brace] a [curly-brace]?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request, synonym-request

Can the tags for [braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/braces) and [curly-braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/curly-braces) be merged or burninated? They both have the exact same usage guidelines.

> [braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/braces) (*131 questions*)
>
> The symbols "{" and "}", commonly used in programming languages. Please use this tag only if the specific usage of these symbols is a relevant part of the question.

> [curly-braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/curly-braces) (*451 questions*)
>
> The symbols "{" and "}", commonly used in programming languages. Please use this tag only if the specific usage of these symbols is a relevant part of the question.

[As per Makoto's suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/355804/3357935), if the community deems the tags unhelpful, burnination may be the best course of action.

Comment: [If all you knew was British English...maybe not.](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/168762/194564)

Comment: More seriously, I wonder what their value is.  Can you justify their existence with a few sample questions for which the tagging is *vital*?

Comment: @Makoto I'm impartial to the tags myself. While I don't see any questions where the tag is *vital*, there are a few questions where it has been used well. ([When do we need curly braces around shell variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8748831/3357935); [What do curly braces in Java mean by themselves?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/241088/3357935); [What's the purpose of using braces (i.e. {}) for a single-line if or loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12193170/3357935))

Comment: My counterargument is that those are tied more to the language or tool itself rather than the fact that they're curly braces.  There's no universal usage of a curly brace unlike there is of an iteration construct like a `for` loop or a `while` loop.

Comment: @Makoto As I said, I'm impartial to whether we keep the tags or not. Either way, it doesn't make much sense to keep both of them separate.

Comment: Before we bother about unification, let's bother about keeping them at all.  No sense in doing any cleanup work if the tags don't need to be around.

Comment: Wait, now @Makoto is having the same point of view?

Comment: One user, @BrentonAlker, has enough rep in either to mark them as synonyms.

Comment: *Somewhere, far far away, a curly brace professor starts crying.*

Comment: Somewhere, *even further away*, a brace of curlers in braces dance on the ice!

Comment: @Makoto no, a *"brace"* is always `{` in British English (and in all dialects of English, as far as I know). You're getting confused with the word *"bracket"*, whose meaning *does* differ between British and American; in British, *"brackets"* means `(` and `)` (and the synonymous word *"parentheses"* is rarely used), while in American, it means `[` and `]` (and the `(` and `)` symbols are referred to as *"parentheses"*).

Comment: @MarkAmery I have never referred to any of these objects as braces, though I'm vaguely familiar with the term. My vocabulary (some version of American English) is `( ... )` parenthesis, `[ ... ]` square bracket, `{ ... }` curly bracket, and `< ... >` bracket. However, the only time I remember using `< .. >` is in HTML variants and refer to the full block itself as a tag, so my memory of the term for `< ... >` is fuzzy at best.

Comment: For reference, [Bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket) on Wikipedia: A **bracket** is a tall punctuation mark typically used in matched pairs within text, to set apart or interject other text. The matched pair may be described as opening and closing, or left and right symbols. Forms include round (also called "parentheses"), square, curly (also called "braces"), and angle brackets; and various other pairs of symbols.

Comment: @MarkAmery:  Yes, I was getting that mixed up with bracket.  Thanks for that clarification.

Comment: @lmo As an American I've called `{` and `}` curly braces for over 35 years of programming but I just noticed that those are called curly brackets in the Unicode standard. And if asked I would refer to '<' and '>' as angle brackets.

Comment: @rmaddy Huh. I hadn't heard the term angle bracket until this post. Live and learn I suppose. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What kind of punctuation is on-topic for <{(\[brackets\])}>?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345165/what-kind-of-punctuation-is-on-topic-for-brackets)

Answer (score 47):

I'll codify this as an answer:

Before we even *bother* with synonymization, let's determine if these tags are worth keeping at all. My initial gut reaction is that they're not, and these tags would be better suited for burnination rather than unification.

I can't think of anything exclusive to braces of any sort that would be universal across languages or technologies. The concept of a blocking structure isn't bound to braces at all.

Therefore, I recommend burnination at best.

Comment: I don't think it needs to be universal across languages or technologies, we have plenty of tags in active use that are not. Other then that I agree, I don't see use for these tags.

Comment: hum, I and what about [tag:brackets]? I would prefer to keep at least one tag to describe the concept of variants of [tag:parenthesis] characters, and [tag:braces] would well fit as a synonym.

Comment: @Cœur:  [There's an IDE called Brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adobe-brackets), and I'm willing to bet most of the questions in the brackets tag are woefully mistagged.

Comment: @Makoto well, it's lucky we don't have a language built on parentheses...

Comment: @Cœur [I beg to dfifer..](http://www.jsfuck.com/)

Comment: _"Therefore, I recommend burnination at best"_ - Intriguing... What do you recommend at _worst_? Torturing everyone who ever used them?

Comment: @AndrewMyers:  You sound like you have a vivid imagination.  Take what you just said and multiply it by a hundred.  You might get close with that. ;)

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure if [braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/braces) or [curly-braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/curly-braces) fill some purpose. What kind of questions would that be, "where do I find { on my keyboard?", "What's this brace thingie for?". I don't think anyone can ask a meaningful question about curly braces by themselves - they mean entirely different things depending on context.

Rather, questions will be about what the curly braces do in the particular language. Most of the time we are speaking of what's formally known as *compound statements*, referring to the pair of `{ }` and everything between them. A tag [compound-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compound-statement) might fill a purpose (doesn't yet exist). Mostly this would fill a purpose for language-lawyer questions regarding syntax.

Alternatively such questions could be about initializer lists, for which we already have a tag [initializer-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/initializer-list). There might be other uses in various languages.

I propose that we burninate both [braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/braces) and [curly-braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/curly-braces), then replace them with what the question is actually asking about, be it compound statements, initializer lists or something else, creating new tags as needed.